# Foursquare does not respect ne and sw params while searching for venues

Tags: foursquare

```
            request.setParameter("query", query)
            .setParameter("ne", ne)
            .setParameter("sw", sw)
            .setParameter("intent", "browse")
                    // This still returns results with empty categories. Fix that.
            .setParameter("categoryId", FOOD_CATEGORY_ID)
            .setParameter("client_id", CLIENT_ID)
            .setParameter("client_secret", CLIENT_SECRET)
            .setParameter("v", "20120101");
```

For `ne = "13.168751,77.750587"`
and `sw = "12.735796,77.377739"`

For query=mcd it returns results from all over the world. This is just an example query - I see this behavior for most queries.

Comment: ping? Can you post your actual request? That or close the question if you're not able to reproduce?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you post the actual request you're making (with the client_secret removed)? When I reconstruct your request, I get properly bound venues: https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/explore#req=venues/search%3Fintent%3Dbrowse%26query%3Dmcd%26ne%3D13.168751,77.750587%26sw%3D12.735796,77.377739

Comment: I could swear that this was not working at the time I posted this question. Works now!